# The cross product - is the result itself a vector or a vector field?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If I take the cross product of a constant vector and a vector field, is the result itself a constant vector or a vector field?

> I.e. say I have a constant vector $\mathbf a=(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$ and a vector field $\mathbf B:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$.
>
> The cross product is explicit
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbf a\times \mathbf B(x,y,z)=
> &\hat e_x(yB_3(x,y,z)-zB_2(x,y,z))\\
> &-\hat e_y(xB_3(x,y,z)-zB_1(x,y,z))\\
> &\hat e_z(xB_2(x,y,z)-yB_1(x,y,z))
> \end{align}
>
> Is this result  a new constant vector, let call it $\mathbf c$, $\mathbf c=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$?
>
> Or is it a new vector field, say, $\mathbf C$, so $\mathbf C:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3?$?

Comment: In general it is a vector field: just write down it to check that.

Comment: If you multiply a constant and a function, is the result a constant or a function?

Comment: A part of the problem is that your constant vector $a = (x, y, z)$ does not look constant. Use $a = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to avoid confusion with variable coordinates.

Comment: @Gribouillis I maybe grasp what you mean. But can I keep $x,y,z$ in the vector field $\mathbf B(x,y,z)$?

Comment: Yes, you can keep $x, y, z$ in $B$, because the difference between a constant vector and a vector field is precisely that the coordinates $B_i(x, y, z)$ of the vector field depend on the position $(x, y, z)$ while the coordinates of a constant vector don't depend on anything. A notation such as $a = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$ would perhaps be even better to stress this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, where $a_i$ are constant, and $ \vec{B}:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3 $, where 
$\vec{B}(x,y,z) = (B_1(x,y,z), B_2(x,y,z),B_3(x,y,z))$.
Then, the cross product: $$ \vec{a}\times\vec{B}(x,y,z) = \hat{e}_x[a_2 B_3(x,y,z)-a_3B_2(x,y,z)] - \hat{e}_y[a_1B_3(x,y,z)-a_3B_1(x,y,z)] + \hat{e}_z[a_1B_2(x,y,z)-a_2B_1(x,y,z)] $$ 
where $(\hat{e}_x,\hat{e}_y,\hat{e}_z)=(\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k})$ are constants.
This makes it a little clearer. So, we can rewrite this as a vector field $v:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, where $$ v(x,y,z):=\vec{a}\times\vec{B}(x,y,z) $$ Thus, for example, if $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a fixed vector, then $$ v(p_1,p_2,p_3)=\vec{a}\times\vec{B}(p_1,p_2,p_3)$$

So indeed it is a vector field.